# C++ printing in signal handlers?

Tags: c++, linux, unix, signals, cout

I searched a lot but none answered my question, I read that it's not safe to use cout in signal handlers like this:

```
void ctrlZHandler(int sig_num) {
    //SIGTSTP-18
    std::cout << "smash: got ctrl-Z" << std::endl;
    SmallShell::route_signal(sig_num);
}
```

1. will it solve the problem if I move the printing inside route_signal?
2. Is there a lists of safe-to-call functions in C++11?
3. What if the only solution to use write, can you show me short example, and let's say route_signal have 100 printings should I replace all with `write()`? that sounds exhausting with the need to allocate memory and free...

Comment: it is unsafe because the buffer while writing to `std::cout`. but you can open `std::cout` to write without buffer ant then it could be safer.

Comment: [signal safety](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) means no memory allocation.  And no buffered I/O, since it won't block signaling (unless you've taken measures to ensure signals are blocked for those routines).  All routines called by the signal handler have the same constraints.

Comment: Please provide some [mre] in your question (some C++ code with a `main`). **At the very least, tell a lot more about your application**. Does it has some event loop? Is it multi-threaded? Do you have access to *all* the source code? Is some C++ code generated by a software (which one)? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67282215/edit) your question to add several paragraphs in it. Read also [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). Spend several hours in reading

Comment: Read also [signal(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and a good [operating system textbook](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)

Comment: Since the context appears to be a `shell` of sorts I'm guessing the main loop is based on something like `select`, `poll` or similar.  If that's the case then you might want to look at the [`self-pipe` trick](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html#NOTES).

Answer (score 5):

Signal handlers need to run quickly and be reentrant, which is why they shouldn’t call output stream functions like cout <<, either directly or indirectly.

If you are doing this temporarily under controlled conditions for testing, it might be okay, but make sure the signal you are handling is not triggered again until the handler has finished and be aware that stream functions can be slow, which might mess up your tests as well.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question in anyway, I didn't ask why it's not safe

Comment: If you know why it is unsafe, you can answer your own question.

Comment: I asked about my own suggestions

Comment: This answers 1, and points you in the right direction for 2 (look for a list of reentrant functions for the environment you are developing for).

Answer (score 5):

The reason why using `std::cout` inside signal handlers isn't recommented is because signals might interrupt your running code whenever and `std::cout::operator <<` is not reentrant.

This means if you are executing `std::cout::operator <<` when a signal is raised that also uses it within it's execution, the result is undefined.

**So, no. Moving it into `route_signal` would not solve this and you should replace every call of `std::cout` within!**

One workaround would be to set a flag that this signal was received and create a output outside the signal handler after it returned.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question in anyway, I didn't ask why it's not safe

Answer (score 1):

> 1. will it solve the problem if I move the printing inside route_signal?

No.

> 2. Is there a lists of safe-to-call functions in C++11?

For practical purposes, the only safe thing you can do is set a `volatile sig_atomic_t` or lock-free atomic flag inside a signal handler. (N3690 *intro.execution* §1.9 ¶6)

I'm no C nor C++ language lawyer, but I believe anything permitted in a conforming C application is allowed in a C++11 signal handler.  However, that set is very, very limited:   `abort`, `quick_exit`, `_Exit`, and `signal`.  (ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.14.1.1 ¶5).

> 3. What if the only solution to use write, can you show me short example, and let's say route_signal have 100 printings should I replace all with write()? that sounds exhausting with the need to allocate memory and free...

A better solution is to redesign your program to use `sigwait` or to check that a flag safely set inside the signal handler.

If you insist on using `write`, and if you trust that it is safe to call inside a signal handler in your C++ implementation — which it probably is but, again, is not guaranteed by C++ itself — then you simply have a coding problem.  You'll need to figure out formatting yourself, bearing in mind that even on POSIX-conforming systems `malloc` and `free` are not async-signal-safe.  It can certainly be done.